# Invalid Hook Call error when running Next app from PM2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, pm2

We have an install of Node.js running on a Windows Server 2012R2 web server.  A developer created an application for us using Next/React/Node (I'm not a web developer so I'm unsure of the specifics of the various development tools used).  This app works fine when manually started on the command line like this:

C:\NodeApps\pacifield>"C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NODE.EXE" C:\NodeApps\pacifield\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next start

However this requires someone to manually login and restart the app whenever the server is rebooted or the app stops for whatever reason.  I am trying to setup PM2 to run the app.  I have it up and running fine until you browse to the app - at which point you get the following error:

```
next-server.ts:306 Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (c:\NodeApps\pacifield\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1476:13)
    at useContext (c:\NodeApps\pacifield\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1484:20)
    at useSession (c:\NodeApps\pacifield\node_modules\next-auth\dist\client\index.js:75:39)
    at Provider (c:\NodeApps\pacifield\node_modules\next-auth\dist\client\index.js:588:12)
    at processChild (C:\NodeApps\pacifield\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3353:14)
    at resolve (C:\NodeApps\pacifield\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3270:5)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (C:\NodeApps\pacifield\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3753:22)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (C:\NodeApps\pacifield\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3690:29)
    at Object.renderToString (C:\NodeApps\pacifield\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:4298:27)
    at Object.renderPage (C:\NodeApps\pacifield\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:596:45)
```

I have checked and there is only the one installation of React in C:\NodeApps\pacifield\node_modules\react and the other suggestions don't seem to make sense when it runs fine outside of PM2.  I have checked with ProcessExplorer that all the environment variables are the same (except for the additional ones PM2 adds) when the app is run from the command line vs. PM2.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hooks can only be call inside of functional component or inside another hook.

take note: [Invalid Hook Call Warning](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)

Notify your frontend developer it.

Comment: Thanks but this does not explain why it works when invoked directly but does not work when run via PM2.

Comment: I think it's almost impossible for you to get an answer to this question, and even if you do, the wrong thing is that it passed and didn't give an error... maybe if you create an issue in next repository you can get some info.

All the best and good luck

Comment: please if you get any information about it, share it with us, maybe it can help other people.